# How do I get the contents of my webbrowser-control to be visible in my MS Access report when printed?

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba, webbrowser-control

Un-answered duplicate here: [MsAccess Webbrowser Control on a Report not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069720/msaccess-webbrowser-control-on-a-report-not-working)

Hello all. I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to do the following:

To make the contents (in this example, a static google map using the api) of my web-browser control visible when my MS Access 2010 report is in print preview and when I export it as a pdf.

For my working example, I have the following three objects in my Access 2010 database:

1) a table - called "tbl_Locations" (which contains location data on three sites)

The table is as follows:

```
LocationID | Location_Name |      Address         | Zip | 

      1          Site A      162 East 33rd street  10016
      2          Site B      550 1st Avenue        10016
      3          Site C      151 West 26th Street  10001
```

[image]

2) a form - called "frm_Locations"(the control source of this form is 'tbl_Locations'). Notably, this is the form that contains the webbrowser-control object (where a static google maps is generated from the data in "tbl_Locations").

Form in Design View:

[image]

Form in Form View:

[image]

3) a report - called "rpt_Locations" (where I have embedded the 'frm_Locations' object)

Report in 'Report' View

[image]

Report in 'Print Preview'

[image]

If you clicked on the picture links above, you could see that the webbrowser-control, and its contents, are visible in the 'Form' view for 'frm_Locations', and 'Report' view for 'rpt_Locations'.

However, this is not the case in the 'Print Preview' view of the 'rpt_Locations'. Additionally, I am unable to see the webbrowser-control, or the static google map within it, when I export the report object as a pdf.

I would like to know why this happens, and if there is a VBA solution I can use to ameliorate this.

Comment: If you check the webbrowser-control's property sheet, is `Display When` (on Format tab) set to Always, not Screen Only?

Comment: @pteranodon: Yes, the 'Display When' property is already set to 'Always'.

Comment: It looks like the Web Control is too big for the page. Did you try re-sizing it?

Comment: @OverMind: I have attempted to re-size the web control. The changes in its size have not influenced the outcome I described above (not viewable in pdf or print preview).

Comment: Have you used forms in reports previously? I never have, and have always ASS/U/MEd that a subreport control can only contain another report. Forms and reports work differently, as evidenced by the differences in events available to each. Given that your control is placed on a form object, rather than on a report object seems to be a logical issue to hold in question. Have you tried putting the WebBrowser control directly into a report object?

Comment: @JohnBingham: Web-browser controls cannot be directly placed on Access reports. That is why I tried to place a web-browser control, indirectly (through a form), onto the report.

Answer (score 2):

Static Maps API seems to return a jpg of a Google Map from a URL

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Then you could load the jpg in your browser or embed the jpg in your report and presumably that would appear in you pdf.

Just like this url

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400

provides this map

[image]

Comment: I added the format parameter argument to the code, and tried tried the static api image in several different formats (jpg amongst them). Adding that parameter still didn't allow me to see (in the report view, or print preview) the static api image in the report object.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read on the web, I'm not sure that it is possible to do this.

I've found a couple of posts which imply hope, but neither indicates concrete success. These are [here](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Printing-Webbrowser-Cont-t2002165.html) and [here](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/683903-how-can-you-display-web-page-within-report)

Alternatively, if instead of trying to do it all from access, you create the pdf first, then you may be able to embed the link you require afterward as shown [here](http://www.planetpdf.com/enterprise/article.asp?ContentID=linking_to_pages_or_destinatio)